# How can I change NumPy array elements from string to int or float?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a data set stored in NumPy array like shown in below, but all the data inside it is stored as string. How can I change the string to `int` or `float`, and store it in back?

```
  data = numpy.array([]) # <--- array initialized with numpy.array
```

in the `data` variable, below information is stored

```
 [['1' '0' '3' ..., '7.25' '' 'S']
  ['2' '1' '1' ..., '71.2833' 'C85' 'C']
   ['3' '1' '3' ..., '7.925' '' 'S']
   ..., 
   ['889' '0' '3' ..., '23.45' '' 'S']
   ['890' '1' '1' ..., '30' 'C148' 'C']
   ['891' '0' '3' ..., '7.75' '' 'Q']]
```

I want to change the first column to int and store the values back. To do so, I did:

```
 data[0::,0] = data[0::,0].astype(int)
```

but, it didn't change anything.

Comment: Do you mean a recarray http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html?

Comment: where does `['1' '0' '3' ..., '7.25' '' 'S']..` come from originally?

Comment: What is the shape and dtype of `data`?

Answer (score 2):

You could set the data type (`dtype`) at `array` initialization. For example if your rows are composed by one 32-bit integer and one 4-byte string you could specify the dtype `'i4, S4'`.

```
data = np.array([(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')], dtype='i4, S4')
```

You could read more about dtypes [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html).

Comment: What is this doing exactly?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You are specifying that the data type (dtype) for each row is a 4-byte integer and a 4-byte string.

Comment: I a not asking for myself, I posted a link in the comments to a recarray already. Some explanation for the OP and how  he/she is going to get the original data object into an array with the first column as an integer would be good.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: In fact it sounded a strange question from someone skilled like you ;) I will add the details to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can make an array that contains strings by starting with lists of strings; note the `S4` dtype:

```
In [690]: data=np.array([['1','0','7.23','two'],['2','3','1.32','four']])

In [691]: data
Out[691]: 
array([['1', '0', '7.23', 'two'],
       ['2', '3', '1.32', 'four']], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

It's more likely that such an array is created by reading a csv file.

I can also view it as an array of single byte strings - the shape and dtype has changed, but the databuffer is the same (the same 32 bytes)

```
In [692]: data.view('S1')
Out[692]: 
array([['1', '', '', '', '0', '', '', '', '7', '.', '2', '3', 't', 'w',
        'o', ''],
       ['2', '', '', '', '3', '', '', '', '1', '.', '3', '2', 'f', 'o',
        'u', 'r']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

In fact, I can change an individual byte, changing the `two` of the original array to `twos`:

```
In [693]: data.view('S1')[0,-1]='s'

In [694]: data
Out[694]: 
array([['1', '0', '7.23', 'twos'],
       ['2', '3', '1.32', 'four']], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

But if I try to change an element of `data` to an integer, it is converted to a string to match the S4 dtype:

```
In [695]: data[1,0]=4

In [696]: data
Out[696]: 
array([['1', '0', '7.23', 'twos'],
       ['4', '3', '1.32', 'four']], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

The same would happen if the number came from `int(data[1,0])` or some variation on that.

But I can trick it into seeing the integer as a string of bytes (represented as `\x04`)

```
In [704]: data[1,0]=np.array(4).view('S4')

In [705]: data
Out[705]: 
array([['1', '0', '7.23', 'twos'],
       ['\x04', '3', '1.32', 'four']], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

Arrays can share data buffers.  The `data` attribute is a pointer to a block of memory.  It's the array's `dtype` that controls how that block is interpreted.  For example I can make another array of ints, and redirect it's `data` attribute:

```
In [714]: d2=np.zeros((2,4),dtype=int)

In [715]: d2
Out[715]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [716]: d2.data=data.data  # change the data pointer

In [717]: d2
Out[717]: 
array([[        49,         48,  858926647, 1936684916],
       [         4,         51,  842214961, 1920298854]])
```

Now `d2[1,0]` is the integer 4.  But the other items are not recognizable, because they are strings viewed as integers.  That's not the same as passing them through the `int()` function.

I don't recommend changing the `data` pointer like this as a regular practice. It would be easy to mess things up.  I had to take care to ensure that `d2.nbytes` was 32, the same as for `data`.

Because the buffer is sharded, a change to `d2` also appears in `data` (but displayed according to a different dtype):

```
In [718]: d2[0,0]=3

In [719]: data
Out[719]: 
array([['\x03', '0', '7.23', 'twos'],
       ['\x04', '3', '1.32', 'four']], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

A view with a complex dtype does something similar:

```
In [723]: data.view('i4,i4,f,|S4')
Out[723]: 
array([[(3, 48, 4.148588672592268e-08, 'twos')],
       [(4, 51, 1.042967401332362e-08, 'four')]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', 'S4')])
```

Notice the `48` and `51` that also appear in `d2`.  The next `float` column is unrecognizable.

That gives an idea of what can and cannot be done 'in-place'.

But to get an array that contains numbers and strings in a meaningful way, I it is better to construct a new structured array.  Perhaps the cleanest way to do that is with an intermediary list of tuples.

```
In [759]: dl=[tuple(i) for i in data.tolist()]

In [760]: dl
Out[760]: [('1', '0', '7.23', 'two'), ('2', '3', '1.32', 'four')]

In [761]: np.array(dl,dtype='i4,i4,f,|S4')
Out[761]: 
array([(1, 0, 7.230000019073486, 'two'), (2, 3, 1.3200000524520874, 'four')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', 'S4')])
```

All these fields take up 4 bytes, so the `nbytes` is the same.  But the individual values have passed through converters.  I have given 'np.array' the freedom to convert values as is consistent for the input and the new dtype.  That's a lot easier than trying to perform some sort of convoluted in-place conversion.

A list tuples with a mix of numbers and strings would also have worked:

```
[(1, 0, 7.23, 'two'), (2, 3, 1.32, 'four')]
```

Structured arrays are displayed a list of tuples. And in the structured array docs, values are always input as list of tuples.

`recarray` can also be used, but essentially that is just a array subclass that lets you access fields as attributes.

If the original array was generated from a csv file, it would have been better to use `np.genfromtxt` (or `loadtxt`) with appropriate options.  It can generate the appropriate list(s) of tuples, and return a structured array directly.

Answer (score 0):

NumPy arrays have associated types for their elements. Assigning to a slice of a NumPy array will up-cast the new data to that type. If that's not possible, the assignment will fail with an exception:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([[1, 2],[3, 4]])
print a
# [[1 2]
#  [3 4]]
print a.dtype
# int64

a[0,0] = 'look, a string'
# ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'a'
```

In your case, `data[0::,0].astype(int)` will produce a NumPy array with associated member type `int64`, but assigning back into a slice of the original array will convert them back to strings.

Other than standard NumPy arrays, [NumPy *record* arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html) mentioned in [Padraic's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500939/how-can-i-change-the-string-to-int-or-float-and-store-it-in-back/31501086#comment50964903_31500939) allow for different types for different columns.

I don't know if a standard NumPy array can be converted to a NumPy *record* array in-place, so constructing one like suggested in [enrico's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31501086/674064) answer with

```
data = np.array([(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')], dtype='i4, S4')
```

might be the best option. If that's not possible, you can construct one from your standard NumPy array and overwrite the variable with the result:

```
import numpy
data = numpy.array([['1', '0', '3', '7.25', '', 'S'],
                    ['2', '1', '1', '71.2833', 'C85', 'C'],
                    ['3', '1', '3', '7.925', '', 'S'],
                    ['889', '0', '3', '23.45', '', 'S'],
                    ['890', '1', '1', '30', 'C148', 'C'],
                    ['891', '0', '3', '7.75', '', 'Q']])
print(repr(data))
# array([['1', '0', '3', '7.25', '', 'S'],
#        ['2', '1', '1', '71.2833', 'C85', 'C'],
#        ['3', '1', '3', '7.925', '', 'S'],
#        ['889', '0', '3', '23.45', '', 'S'],
#        ['890', '1', '1', '30', 'C148', 'C'],
#        ['891', '0', '3', '7.75', '', 'Q']], 
#       dtype='|S7')

data = numpy.core.records.fromarrays(data.T, dtype='i4,S4,S4,S4,S4,S4')
print(repr(data))
# rec.array([(1, '0', '3', '7.25', '', 'S'), (2, '1', '1', '71.2', 'C85', 'C'),
#        (3, '1', '3', '7.92', '', 'S'), (889, '0', '3', '23.4', '', 'S'),
#        (890, '1', '1', '30', 'C148', 'C'), (891, '0', '3', '7.75', '', 'Q')], 
#       dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '|S4'), ('f2', '|S4'), ('f3', '|S4'), ('f4', '|S4'), ('f5', '|S4')])
```

Comment: Does someone know whether an in-place conversion is possible or how a record array would be constructed from a standard NumPy array? @PadraicCunningham, maybe?

Comment: Not sure about inplace but if data was a list of python lists you could `np.array(list(map(tuple, data)), dtype="i4,S4,S4,S4,S4,S4")`, if it was an array you could `np.core.records.fromarrays(data.T,dtype="i4,S4,S4,S4,S4,S4"))`

Comment: Inplace conversions have to leave the total data buffer size unchanged.  'i4' dtypes can be changed for 4 'i1' types, or (I think) 4 `s1'.  But interpreting strings as ints or floats will change the number of bytes, and can't be done in-place.